# Woocommerce auto cancel On-Hold after X days

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I have searched high and low but with no resolve. So we developed a custom "bacs" type gateway for our site. Here in Brazil you can pay via a bank billet. The billet usually has an expiration date for payment (around 7 days). So when a person goes through check-out the gateway sends the billet to our customer and he has to pay until the expiring date.

Since this is an offline payment, the order status goes to "on-hold". What I have been looking for is a way to specify that on-hold orders get canceled automatically after 8 days (since there's a 7 day limit).

If seen some code where people hook the pending order cancelation time-out but it seems like that wouldn't be the case. Any ideias?

Comment: Set up a cron that checks the date and updates the status. Set it up as a true cron instead of just the default WP implementation where it only triggers when people visit the site.

Answer (score 1):

So I got this working. I created a plugin and with a few hours running around several forums and a lot of help I got to something very interesting.

So call in orders, bacs, and all of the other types of offline orders are put on hold until payment is verified. The post_status is 'wc-on-hold'. What we needed was to exclude our rule to Checks, since we don't need to deal with expiration dates. This is the code we got to:

```
// To change the amount of days just change '-7 days' to your liking
function get_unpaid_submitted() {        
            global $wpdb;

            $unpaid_submitted = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
                    SELECT posts.ID
                    FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS posts
                    WHERE posts.post_status = 'wc-on-hold'
                    AND posts.post_date < %s
            ", date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-7 days') ) ) );

            return $unpaid_submitted;
    }

    // This excludes check payment type.
    function wc_cancel_unpaid_submitted() {        
            $unpaid_submit = get_unpaid_submitted();

            if ( $unpaid_submit ) {                
                    foreach ( $unpaid_submit as $unpaid_order ) {                        
                            $order = wc_get_order( $unpaid_order );
                            $cancel_order = True;

                            foreach  ( $order->get_items() as $item_key => $item_values) {                                
                                    $manage_stock = get_post_meta( $item_values['variation_id'], '_manage_stock', true );
                                    if ( $manage_stock == "no" ) {                                        
                                            $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method();                                        
                                            if ( $payment_method == "cheque" ) {
                                                    $cancel_order = False;
                                            }
                                    }                                
                            }
                            if ( $cancel_order == True ) {
                                    $order -> update_status( 'cancelled', __( 'Pagamento não identificado e cancelado.', 'woocommerce') );
                            }
                    }
            }        
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_submitted', 'wc_cancel_unpaid_submitted' );
    /* End of code. */
```

Comment: @daniel-remagnoli remember to mark you own answer as a solution, if the question is answered.